# Поиск по БД (Access) в Delphi

Tags: delphi, access

Имеется `edit1` на `form1`. Как сделать, чтобы при вводе туда слова (на событие `TForm1.Edit1Change`), которое содержится в одной из таблиц, названия которых можно выбрать в `combobox1`, данные выводились через `ShowModal` в виде таблицы на `DBGrid` из базы, которая лежит в рядом с программой?

(Слова могут быть в разных таблицах, нужно выводить полную строку из каждой таблицы `db.mdb`.)

Answer (score 0):

Подключи базу данных с помощью компонентов ADOConnection ADOQuery Dataset и тд..И осуществляй поиск с помощью SQL-запросов.